# java serialization across networks data integrity

Tags: java, serialization, data-integrity

How to ensure data integrity when sending serialized objects across networks.
Implemented example would be helpful.
One way could be to use java.io.Externalizable with java.security.MessageDigest
But this is requires a manual serialization.
I think that is bit risky, so i would not want to use it.
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [`javax.crypto.SealedObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/SealedObject.html) or [`java.security.SignedObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SignedObject.html).

Comment: encryption != signature. It seems like the OP wants to ensure that no man in the middle changed what has been sent, and doesn't want to make it confidential.

Comment: @JB Nizet is correct.. I am trying to come up with a code to clarify my question